# NPM publish will copy the all files to NPM server or not?

Tags: npm

I am successfully publish a package by following [this official tutorial](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages):
Does it mean NPM copy all my files to NPM server? Because the command I use is:

```
npm publish
```

No other params.

Whereas in Bower, the command I use is:

```
bower register raphael.backbone git://github.com/tomasAlabes/backbone.raphael.git
```

It is clearly the source is git repo, so bower is clearly a registry, not copying the project files.

**Question:**

"NPM publish " will copy my files to NPM server or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm publish` compresses your current working directory into a tarball and uploads it to the npm registry; so yes, `npm publish` will copy your files to npm server.

You actually don't have to use git for an npm package, though using it is a good idea to use version control for any software development.

Comment: Do you know if "Bower register" will copy all files from git url to bower server?

Comment: Not positive, but I think it installs directly from GitHub.

Comment: I think bower copy the files from git repo, since Bower logs out "download...", "extract archive zip"